# Disable debuggin generate error on xamarin forms ios

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

my problem: i must generate ipa, so if i set Enable Debugging like deselect, visual studio return an error.
How to solve ? i need that my Ipa don't have debug code inside.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a guide on this here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ipa_support/#Creating_an_IPA

Comment: the guide not solve my problem, i generated ipa some days ago, but now I get release build without debug code. but if i deselect the option visual studio not build, but return me an error.

Comment: @Mr. Developer, the same issue has been reported to the Xamarin forum: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31626/ios-release-build-in-visual-studio-shows-error-debug-is-not-enabled-in-the-current-configuration, please check that whether it is related to the Xamarin version.